# Iterate over java.util.set in scala and create new java.util.hashset

Tags: scala, scala-java-interop

I have `java` API which returns `java.util.set`, I want to iterate over the `set` till the `size-1` and create new `java.util.hashset` in scala

I tried following :

```
val keys = CalltoJavaAPI()
val newHashSet = new java.util.HashSet()
val size = keys.size();
newHashSet.add(keys.take(keys.size() - 1))
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractCollection.add(AbstractCollection.java:221)
```

Tried Following but still not working

```
    val keys = CalltoJavaAPI().asScala        
    var newHashSet = new scala.collection.mutable.HashSet[Any]()
    newHashSet.add(keys.take(keys.size - 1))
```

Comment: have you tried anything yet? thats the only way we can helpt you ;)

Comment: Are you sure the exception is thrown on that line? As you can see from the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#AbstractCollection.add%28java.lang.Object%29) (and also from your exception) the `UnsupportedOperationException` is thrown from `AbstractCollection`, which is impossible if you call `.add(Object)` on a `HashSet`, because it overrides the behavior (see the [source](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/HashSet.java#HashSet.add%28java.lang.Object%29)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `scala.collection.JavaConversions` for implicit conversions between Scala and Java collections.

In the following approach we convert a Java `HashSet` onto a Scala `Set`, extract keys of interest, and convert the result onto a new Java `HashSet`:

```
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._

val javaKeys = new java.util.HashSet[Any](CalltoJavaAPI()) 
val n = javaKeys.size 

val scalaSet = javaKeys.toSet.take(n-1)

val newJavaHashSet = new java.util.HashSet[Any]()
newJavaHashSet.addAll(scalaSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use `newHashSet.addAll(...)` instead of `newHashSet.add(...)` since `keys.take(...)` returns a `List`.

From the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add%28E%29):

> public boolean add(E e): Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
>
> public boolean addAll(Collection c): Adds all of the elements in the specified collection to this collection